# Table Name is populating instead of table value in CSV Export format - SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, export-to-csv

SSRS 2005 Export issue

When 'No Data' - In the CSV Export Format - Table Name, Textbox Name is populating instead of Table value,Textbox vale.

I browsed and find few solution but its couln't help.

Changes I did: In the Table property, have set the

```
DataElementName is Empty,DataElementOutput is Output, DetailDataElementOutput is Output
```

***Note: All other Export formats and report output is looks good***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution:

Yes, when we have 'No search result' we are getting tableName and textBoxName into the CSV Export file.

Please find the below steps to solve the above issue

Step 1: Add the below set of lines into Result SP or Select Query

```
        -- Ur final Select Code
   UNION ALL    
        -- You can add n number of NULL select value it depends on how much you return 
    SELECT NULL,NULL,'---EOF---',NULL,NULL
```

Step 2: Rename all the Textbox name in the Table into relavant header name

> Ex: S NO to S_No, Table Name to Table_Name

Since exporting into CSV you can see the valid data.

I followed above steps to solve my query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try using DataElementOutput as AUTO and check.